# Convert year and day of year to calender date in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Need to convert "15307" in to something like "2015-11-03"

I have the following code

```
def juliantoregular(date1)
    temp = "20" + date1[0,2];
    year = temp.to_i;        
    if date1[2,1] == "0"      
       temp1 = date1[3,2];
    else
        temp1 = date1[2,3];
    end 
    juliannumber = temp1.to_i;
    date1 = Date.ordinal(year,juliannumber) 
    return date1;
end
```

Input to the code is String "15307" is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

[`Date.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) is perfect for this:

```
str = "15307"
puts Date.strptime(str, "%y%j")
# => 2015-11-03
```

In the format string `"%y%j"`, `%y` indicates a two-digit year and `%j` indicates day of the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
y, d = "15307".to_i.divmod 1_000     #⇒ [15, 307]
Date.parse("20#{y}-01-01") + (d - 1) #⇒ add days to Jan, 1st
#⇒ #<Date: 2015-11-03 ((2457330j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: `Date.parse("20#{Y}-01-01") seems like an expensive way to construct a that Date. Why not `Date.new(2000 + y)`?

Comment: @Jordan Indeed. Your way is nevertheless better; upvoted.